# Where to find stock images (portraits) with transparent background

Tags: transparency, images, background, mask, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a place to find stock images, specifically portraits, that come with a pre-masked background, so I can easily replace it. Does anyone know a source, or a way to filter for that type of image?

Comment: Know a filter? Filter for web searches to find only portraits with transparent background or the extremely popular once-click faultless background removal effect?

Comment: I just googled «How to be funny» on Stackoverflow and your comment popped up :0, you nailed it.